# Vue v-bind how works

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have a simple code for select in Vue.

```
 <select class="form-control"v-model="complaint.no_document_reason">
     <option v-for="(value, key) in noDocReason" v-bind:value="key">{{ value }} </option>  
 </select>
```

I wonder why it works only when I add `v-bind:value='key'`, but when I want to add `:value ='{{key}}'`, then I doesn't.

My question is why? I read in documentation that It should work in my two ways. Can someone explain me why I should use here `v-bind` instead `value=''`?

Comment: [Inline interpolation (`value="{{key}}"`) was removed in Vue v2](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Interpolation-within-Attributes-removed). If you read somewhere that you can do that, it was referring to Vue v1.

Comment: @thanksd oh god You're right... So in Vue 2 there is v-bind only for dynamic changed charakters? Like values, classes or styles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

v-bind makes attribute dynamic you can write both `v-bind:value="key"` and `:value="key"`

You can not use `attribute="{{}}"` in attributes, to make them dynamic use `v-bind:attribute=""` or `:attribute=""`

Comment: But when I have dynamic attribute I can only use v-bind:attribute. In Vue 2 there is no attribute:={{}}. Am I right?

Comment: There are two ways: v-bind:value="" and :value="", both do the same, :value="" is shorter.